# Can an IT firm have no-shop clause in offer letter?

Tags: employment, legal-terms

I got an offer letter from an IT company and in this offer letter below statement was mentioned.

> Also please note that by signing this letter, you agree to “**No shop terms**” (for the period starting from date of signing
> the Offer Letter till applicable notice days i.e., 90 days from the date of joining, you agree not to interview with other
> entities and abide by basic work ethics), which is legally binding to both the parties.

Then I asked the HR what is this term. She told me it's just to find the intent of candidate whether they would like to join the company.

Then I signed this offer letter and joined the company but now I am not willing to work here. Also I have got another offer too.

What will happen if I leave this company by official informing them and join some other company within 1-2 weeks?

Hope to have relevant response.

Thanks

Comment: Location might help, since such clauses may or may not be enforceable in those jurisdictions. Personally I would not have signed that offer.

Comment: Also never rely on explanations or "clarifications" the counterparty makes outside the contract. Unless the contract itself is inconclusive, those "clarifications" are not relevant, let alone binding. If something in the contract is unclear, it is in your best interest to require more specificity.

Comment: Contracts usually have a breach section that says what happens if your break it.